# Run Script if CheckBox is checked

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a sheet where I am recording multiple check boxes with =COUNTIF($B$2,TRUE). However, when I check a specific checkbox I am hoping to run a script $B$16. At this writing no matter what checkbox I click the script is executed.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hXs0KWv_HnWwIej2nF5NxlMEarDWy-3TnGuH4fDGmpQ/edit?usp=sharing

My trigger is recordValue, fromSpreadsheet, onEdit

Thanks for any insight,
David

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Comment: Kindly provide  [mcve] and a sample table data

Answer (score 3):

#### Run code where checkbox in B16 is checked

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet(); 
  if(sh.getName() == 'Sheet Name' && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart == 16 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    //put your code here
  }
}
```

Comment: e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart == 16  can be replaced as range.getA1Notation() == 'B16'

Comment: Yes but that requires a function call and by using e.range.rowStart and e.range.columnStart is already available in the event object.  So it save  you some time in a function that must complete in 30 seconds.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: e.range comes with getA1Notation() function.  Anyway , it all works , just few more codes.

Comment: yes but it is a function call and it takes time.